# Highlight custom color for the Mean Value data cell of every column in heatmap using pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to Highlight the Mean Value cell or Lowest value cell of Mean value in pandas heatmap but it always giving failure result for me. I wants to Highlight the cell of Exact mean value in the heatmap if exact value not available means need to highlight lowest value for the meanvalue.

For Ex: Meanvalue is 17.522 but not available in df means need to highlight 15.499 (refer

Here I have Shared Screen shots of What I tried and What is my Expectation for your ref.

Genius Always Welcome..! Thanks in Advance.

Each Column Mean Values are,

```
array([17.60950419, 33.73034387, 46.63401871, 56.27580645, 52.62956452,
       63.70669355, 71.75735484, 67.788     , 83.62327419, 75.41342   ])
```

I have tried following code to Highlight the single cell

```
df_Mean=np.array(df.mean())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,8))

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["#f9f9f9","#B6DBF2","#327AD9","#3068D9"])
color = ["#f9f9f9",'#3068D9',"#f9f9f9","#f9f9f9","#B6DBF2","#327AD9","#3068D9"]

ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt=".5g", linewidths=.02, 
                 cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=300,cbar_kws={'label': 'Si.No'}, 
                linecolor='#CBDBD7',
                ax = ax,
                xticklabels=1, yticklabels=1,
                )

ax = sns.heatmap(df.round(),mask=(df > df_Mean),
             vmin=10, vmax=80, cmap=color, cbar=False)

ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

ax.set_xticklabels(
    ax.get_xticklabels(), color = 'darkgreen',
    horizontalalignment='center');

ax.set_yticklabels(
    ax.get_yticklabels(), color = 'darkblue',
    horizontalalignment='right',
    size = 10,);

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=20)  

plt.xlabel('Month', color = 'Maroon', size= 15)
plt.title('Testing_HeatMap', color = 'darkgreen', size = 20)
plt.show()
```

I am getting this Output,
[image: I am getting this Output]

Expected Output is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I've demonstrated a solution on some random data (but it should illustrate the method for your set up).

For each column I find the row number of the value closest to the column mean, which is less than or equal to the column mean:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Generate some random data (25 rows, 3 columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25, 3))

# Compute the mean of each column
df_mean = df.mean()

# Find the difference between each value and the column mean
diff = df - df.mean()

# We are only interested in values less than or equal to the mean
mask = diff <= 0

# The row numbers of the closest values to the column mean
# which are less than or equal to the column mean
highlight_row = np.nanargmin(np.array(df[mask]), axis=0)
```

Once you've got these row numbers the only remaining thing to do is to plot them. One way to do this would be using the `Rectangle` patch (although there are undoubtedly other ways to do this):

```
# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax)

# Loop over the columns
for col in range(df.shape[1]):
    # Add a rectangle which highlights our cell of interest
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((col, highlight_row[col]), 1, 1))
```